# WebStorm-like version control in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I've mostly switched to Visual Studio Code from WebStorm for my Node.js development.

For the most part, I'm able to do everything in VSCode, however I find that the VCS implemented in VSCode is lacking compared to WebStorm's.

In particular, I find WebStorm's conflict resolution when rebasing feature branches much more user friendly.

And so I was wondering if there is anything equivalent to WebStorm's 'VCS -> Git -> Resolve Conflicts...' feature in VSCode.

Comment: Yea I still find myself opening up Intellij when it comes for resolving conflicts. IDEA's merge tool makes it so much easier and I'm not afraid I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature for VS code. But you can install some git extensions to view and resolve conflict files easily.

Such as you can install the extension [Git Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens), and when you open conflict files -> click Toggle File Blame, there will shows which lines were you committed and which lines are new add, then you can modify with the what you need.

[image]

Or you can use **Visual studio** instead (VS has the resolve conflicts feature similar as webstorm). In Team explorer -> Branches -> select the branch you need to rebase -> rebase -> IF there has conflicts -> click conflicts -> open a conflict file -> Merge.

[image] [image]
[image]

In the merge window, you can select the version you want to use -> add changes you need in result window -> Accept Merge -> view changes -> enter message -> commit.

[image]